# Yo necesito una explicación en cuanto al hecho de que, a veces, no se usan verbos como levantarse sin la forma de reflexivo

Tags: pronombres, reflexivos

Por ejemplo,

> yo levanto la mano (no levantarse)

Pero,

> Yo me peino el pelo

Comment: Mano es femenino a pesar de la terminación en _-o_

Answer (score 3):

En efecto hay verbos que siempre necesitan ir con un pronombre. Se llaman [verbos pronominales (o pronominados)](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbo_pronominal)

> El verbo pronominal es aquel que se conjuga con un pronombre átono en todas sus formas (me, te, se, os, le, lo, la, les, los, las, se, nos).

Hay verbos **estrictamente pronominales**, que son los que **siempre** necesitan este pronombre. *Peinar* lo pudes usar sin un pronombre

> Yo peino a mi hijo

Hay verbos como *morir*, *callar* o *caer* en los que simplemente cambia un matiz al usar sus formas reflexivas. El pronombre reflexivo cambia el sentido del verbo, acentuar la acción o indicar que la acción afecta directamente al sujeto.

> Me caí y casi me mato

Pero *arrepentirse* o *fugarse* por ejemplo siempre tiene que llevar el pronombre

> Me arrepiento. Te arrepientes. Se arrepiente.
>
> Los presos se fugaron de la carcel.

Estos suelen ser verbos en los que el beneficio de la acción recae siempre (o sólo puede recaer) sobre el sujeto que la realiza. Nadie puede "arrepentir" a otra persona. Nadie puede "fugarse" por otra persona. Nadie va a recibir el beneficio de la acción salvo la propia persona que la realiza. El sujeto y el agente, que pueden ser distintos, pero siempre ejercen sobre sí mismos una acción en su beneficio o en su provecho.

En estos verbos pronominales pueden no tener complemento directo como los intransitivos.

Hay [varios grupos de verbos pronominales](http://www.hispanoteca.eu/Lexikon%20der%20Linguistik/v/VERBOS%20PRONOMINALES.htm):

- Reflexivos internos o pronominales: corresponden a verbos intransitivos (sin objeto directo) y cuya forma activa correspondiente tiene un sentido diferente (o no existe): levantarse, lanzarse, arrepentirse, espantarse, avergonzarse, etc.
- Verbos reflexivos y recíprocos: el complemento del verbo, idéntico al sujeto de la oración activa, se sustituye por un pronombre reflexivo singular o plural (La niña peina a la niña --> la niña se peina; Cada niña peina a la otra niña--> las niñas se peinan)
- Reflexivos indirectos o reflexivos de interés: presentan un complemento directo distinto del pronombre reflexivo (Cóme**te** (tú) este pastel [pastel es el CD])
- Pasiva refleja: construcción reflexiva con sentido pasivo (Se venden pisos. Se arreglan ordenadores)

Así que resumiendo:

- Hay verbos que no pueden ir si el pronombre reflexivo, porque la acción recae en provecho del sujeto o agente
- No todos los verbos necesitan el pronombre. A veces lo llevan y esto cambia el sentido del verbo. El que lo llevo o lo necesite, depende mucho del complemento directo y quien se beneficia de la acción.

Nota (de los comentarios):

> Yo me levanto la mano

Dirías esto sólo si estás por ejemplo usando una de tus manos para levantarte la otra. Es "me" tiene el sentido de "a mi mismo". Lo normal sería "yo levanto la mano". "La mano" es quien recibe la acción. Con "yo **me** levanto la mano" tú serías el beneficiario de la acción.

> Yo peino a X /// Yo **me** peino (a mi mismo)

La acción puede recaer sobre distintos agentes

> Yo **me** arrepiento.

Con este verbo la acción sólo puede recaer sobre la persona que realiza la acción. Puedo pedirte que te arrepientas pero el beneficiario de la acción vas a ser tu igualmente.

Comment: No veo que nada de esto explique por qué no decimos *yo me levanto la mano*, como haríamos con muchos otros verbos (*me peino el pelo*, *me lavo los dientes*, *me toco la nariz*, *me rasco la mano*...). El verbo *levantar* es pronominal en otros casos (*yo me levanto*).

Comment: Yo entiendo, por el título, que la pregunta es porqué algunos verbos parece ser que no pueden ir sin el pronombre (reflexivo). Los ejemplos de la pregunta (peinar y levantar) son de hecho verbos que pueden ir con o sin el pronombre. He intentado explicar porqué otros verbos (_estrictamente pronominales_ como _arrepentirse_, _fugarse_) no pueden ir sin el pronombre. En cualquier caso, intentaré aclarar un poco más la respuesta. Gracias por la crítica constuctiva.

Comment: Vale, ahora lo veo. Lo cierto es que no entendía por qué *levantar* no era pronominal en este caso y tu respuesta no me lo aclaraba, pero ahora lo veo claro. La idea es que, en unos casos, realizo una acción con una parte de mi cuerpo sobre otra distinta (pronominales) y en otros, como el ejemplo *yo levanto la mano* (podría ser *yo muevo la pierna*...) no, ¿verdad?

Comment: Depende mucho de si el verbo tiene complemento directo y quién es el beneficiario de la acción. "Yo muevo la mano" es como "yo muevo el vaso" (tiene CD) aunque la mano sea mía. "Yo me muevo la mano" tiene carácter reflexivo (a mí mismo), que modifica el sentido del verbo, como en "yo me caigo" o "yo me peino". Puedes decir "yo me peino a mi mismo" pero no "yo me caigo a mi mismo" por que "peinar" es transitivo (espera CD) y "caer" no. Aparte, hay verbos en los que la acción o su beneficio sólo puede caer sobre quien la realiza ("arrepentirse"). Espero haberlo aclarado un poco más...