# Why is " me" used in "Se me descompuso el auto"?

Tags: sintaxis, reflexivos

"Se descompuso el auto" translates as The car broke down.

"Se **me** descompuso el auto" translates as My car broke down.

Can someone explain the use of 'me' in the second sentence?
Is this a common way of expressing possession?

Comment: Relacionadas: [“Voy a dormir” vs “me voy a dormir” - huge difference or not?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20035/5481)... [Yo necesito una explicación en cuanto al hecho de que, a veces, no se usan verbos como levantarse sin la forma de reflexivo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/11886/5481)... [¿Por qué dicen “me vi la película”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/8498/5481)... [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre “se me olvidó” y “olvidé”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3300/5481)... [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre comer y comerse?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2890/5481)

Comment: Welcome Dae. See if any of the provided questions (or any other [under the tag "reflexivos"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reflexivos) already answers your question. It is really similar to others we had. Feel free to reach us if you have any questions about how this site works.

Comment: I'm not sure the related questions that have been pointed out to dae will help in this case, as they either have no accepted answers or the answers don't explain what's happening in this case. This looks like a dative of interest to me.

Comment: @pablodf76 I agree. I didn't include them as "possible duplicate of" but as "other questions that include either `se` or `me` or both", just to point to additional learning resources. I added the tag "reflexivos" myself, and I just wanted to point out to this new user the existence of such questions and the site capabilities to search using tags. As we know mastering it can be difficult to master "reflexivos" for non native speakers, so I thought additional readings could help.

Comment: Voy a sacar esta pregunta de las colas de revisión ya que las respuestas de las otras preguntas no responden tan bien a este caso particular como las que se están aportando en esta pregunta. Por tanto, entiendo que es mejor dejarla abierta y con sus propias respuestas.

Comment: I've voted to close as a duplicate of https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23890/9385.  I hope my answer there helps you understand your sentence.  If not, please edit your question!  (Just click where it says "edit" below your question.)

Answer (score 5):

*Me* indicates **whose** car broke down.

Se **me** descompuso el carro. My car broke down
Se **te** descompuso el carro. Your car broke down
Se **le** descompuso el carro. His/her car..
Se **les**... .Their car..

Se descompuso el carro = The car broke down (whose car is not specified)

Answer (score 3):

I agree with both pablodf76 and AlfonsoPC that we are faced with a **dative of interest** that indicates **possession**.

In [this article](http://hispanoteca.eu/Gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Dativos%20superfluos.htm) we can read, under *Dativo posesivo o simpatético*, the following:

> El dativo posesivo es, en rigor, un subtipo del dativo de interés, puesto que el poseedor es afectado por el proceso. Es uno de los diferentes valores semánticos que pueden asignarse al complemento llamado específicamente dativo, o al objeto indirecto, en el sentido más amplio de este término. En los ejemplos:
>
> **Le** cerraron los ojos. (*They closed **his/her** eyes*.)
>
> **Me** duele la cabeza. (***My** head hurts*.)
>
> **Le** sale sangre por la nariz. (***His** nose is bleeding*.)
>
> el pronombre personal en dativo equivale a un posesivo: **sus** ojos, **mi** cabeza, **su** nariz.

[The bolds and translations are mine.]

Although we can say in correct Spanish:

- **Mi** auto se descompuso.

we tend to reserve this construction for animate subjects (***Mi** amiga se descompuso*) and use the dative of interest to couple the possession with the benefit/harm meaning (the owner of the car being affected by its breakdown in the case of *Se **me** descompuso el auto*).